# Meaning of ここで引くなどご法度

Tags: meaning, usage, particle-など

> ここで引くなどご法度

I've read several articles on *nado*, and have found that it can mean 'whatnot, and such, etc.' but to me that doesn't make sense here. Can anyone help with this?

Comment: 引く　＝　 play、bedraggle、refer、consult、look up、cast、draw、pull back // So the translation would be "here It is forbidden to (引く）etc."  // Unable to grasp the context from the sentence.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ここで引く**など**ご法度 ≂ ここで引く**なんて**、ご法度（だ）。

The など in your example is definition #❸-㋑ in 明鏡国語辞典:

> など〘副助詞〙
>   ❸ 軽んじる気持ちをこめて取り上げる。
>   ㋑ 《活用語の言い切りの形に付いて、発言や思考の表現を伴って》おおよその内容を、反発の気持ちをこめて示す。「今さら行く**など**と言ってももう遅い。」「許してもらおう**など**という甘い考えは捨てろ。」

It's a belittling / derogatory suffix, close in meaning and usage to なんて.
When attached to the end-form of 活用語(conjugatable words) and used with a quoted remark or an expression of thoughts, it indicates the feeling/emotion of opposing, rejecting or denying the preceding part.

ご[法度]{はっと} means "(strictly) forbidden; banned; taboo", or "out of the question".
The 引く here is like "withdraw; retreat; back out; back down".
ここで is literally "here" or "in this situation", but it can mean "after coming this far" "now that it's come to this" or "now that we've reached a point of no return".

Put together, ここで引くなどご法度 can mean "Now that it's come to this, I'm/you're never allowed to withdraw" / "I/You can't possibly back down after coming this far", or more concisely, "I/You can't back down now."

Comment: That's very interesting, @Shoko! Is it a rare term?

Comment: など used this way is quite common, but yes, the word ご法度 sounds a bit literary/old, and might be a bit rare. Average Japanese would know its meaning, but it's not a word we'd actively use in daily conversation.

Answer (score 1):

"ここで引くのはご法度" is the old-fashioned common phrase.

> "ここで引くのはご法度" = "「ここで引く」と言うことは、ご法度"

The meanng "引く" of "引くなどご法度" is "to quit."

"ご法度{はっと}" is "prohibited matter".

So "引くなどご法度" means "Quitting is not allowed."

"ここで" means "この場面で" = "in this situation"

If you quit something, and it shows up your weakness or dishonesty, someone by you or you yourself say "ここで引くなどご法度."

Anyway, it extreamly old-fassioned phrase. Nowadays we just can hear it in the doramatic entertainment.