# What is など in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, particle-など

> 痛みを伴わない教訓には意味が無い・・・
>
> 人は何かの犠牲なしに何も得る事などできないのだから

I usually see など used like "etc. / things like / and others", I was wondering if it's the same word here, though it sounds kind of odd if I put it this way.. I don't really understand what it adds to the sentence.

Speaking of humans, that is why without something as a sacrifice, nothing etc.. is able to be obtained.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/33289/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/60238/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/39383/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/43488/9831

Comment: Can you double check you've copied the quote correctly? I think it should be 人は何かの犠牲**なし**に何も得る事などできないのだから to make sense.

Comment: @Chocolate My apologies, I did mistype that part. My attempt to apply my understanding from the links you sent, I think it is used to belittle / look down on the "nothing" that is gained.